# CSS: How to vertically align text in span right aside a responsive image (also in span)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align text right aside an image (both: text and image are in a span element enclosed by another container). If I set the image to a fixed size, everything works as expected (vertical-align: middle does its job). If I'm making it responsive, the text is not anymore vertically aligned. What am I doing wrong here?

```
body {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-size:  2vmin;
}

#first_header {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    }

#img_header {

    width: 60%;
    display: table-cell;
}

header span {
    width: 30%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;

}
```

---

```
<header id="first_header">
        <span>
            <img id="img_header" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        </span>
        <span>
            Test
        </span>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `transform` properties to solve your problem with the code below for your text:

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `calc(50% - calc(16px / 2))`, where 16px is the font size.

Answer (score 0):

use flexBox:

```
header{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```